# CMake with crypt(3)

Tags: cmake, crypt

I trying to make a `crypt(3)` sample with CMake.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <crypt.h>

/* To compile: $ gcc check.c -lcrypt -o check */
int main(void) {
  /* Hashed form of "GNU libc manual". */
  char *pass = "$1$/iSaq7rB$EoUw5jJPPvAPECNaaWzMK/";
  /* Read in the user’s password and encrypt it,
     passing the expected password in as the salt. */
  char *result = crypt(getpass("Password:"), pass);
  /* Test the result. */
  int ok = strcmp (result, pass) == 0;

  puts(ok ? "Access granted." : "Access denied.");
  return ok ? 0 : 1;
}
```

To build it it should be pass the `-lcrypt` option to gcc.
My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
project(cryptexample)
set(SOURCE_FILES check.c)
add_executable(check ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

How can I pass this option and build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
target_link_libraries(check crypt)
```

Source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html